# Quartz Enterprise Job Scheduler 2 - Working Example needed

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I am implementing a POC with Quartz Enterprise Job Scheduler 2.0. Along with this I need to connect the Quartz manager (UI application) to my Scheduler and access the DB to view/edit the job details. I am unable to get pass the initial connection set up as the UI is unable to connect to my scheduler. I have exposed the scheduler with rmi and i was able to verify that rmi running. But the manager UI is unable to connect to the scheduler.

Please provide some inputs to resolve this issue.

Also pointers to any working Quartz 2 examples available will be very helpful.

Thanks,
RJ.

Answer (score 0):

The manager does not connect to the RMI interface, it uses the JMX interface.  Set your quartz properties to export the JMX interface.